# Ubuntu: Mounted internal drive permissions

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have a drive,`sda6`, mounted as `/scratch` on my Ubuntu 10.10 system. It has the corresponding line `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=598e96c8-ec9d-43a0-aa48-b42ba8beef9c /scratch        ext4    defaults        0       2
```

However, the permissions on `/scratch` are writable only by root. I'd really like it to be world writable, and to maintain this across reboots. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/scratch` is ext4, so you would use `chown`, `chmod`, `[gs]etfacl` et alia to control permissions.

Comment: My understanding is that this would _not_ work across reboots.

Comment: It's ext4. The permissions are recorded on the media.